# Lucene index multilingual complex entity

Tags: .net, lucene.net, multilingual, lucene

I have the following classes:

```
public class Resource
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public IList<LocalizedValue> LocalizedValues { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedValue
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is used to store multilingual data in other objects, like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public Resource Description { get; set; }

    // some other properties...
}
```

So I'm able to store the description in several languages.

I would like to index the `Job` object (including its `Resource` properties) in Lucene.Net in order to be able to search something either in all languages or in a specified one.

I looked at the other relevant questions on SO or elsewhere, but I'm not really sure about what to do.

I considered using several fields (one for each TextValue of each Resource in the Job class), but how can I identify which language the text is in without falling into quite complex queries ?

I suppose I'll be able to manage one way or another, but I still ask just in case someone has a great idea I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create N + 1 fields, 1 for each language and 1 where you put everything in.

```
doc.addField("EN", //english stuff);
doc.addField("NL", //dutch stuff);
doc.addField("all", //english stuff and dutch stuff);
```

In this scenario, if you would search within a specific language, use that field. If you want to search in all languages, use `all`

If you want to figure out which language it is in when searching the `all` field; you cannot do that easily. You can use `N` boolean queries (`all` AND `EN`), (`all` AND `NL`).

Or perhaps better, create `facets` for all language-fields. Then you can retrieve the facetscounts for each language field in one (quick) query. The highest scoring facet will be the language that matches the search.